# How do I list all pypi packages from a given author or maintainer without logging in?

Tags: python, pypi, cheeseshop

When I log in to [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/), I see this.

[image: Screenshot of tlevine's packages on PyPI]

Can I get something like this without logging in?
For example, is there something like NPM's
[/~tlevine](https://www.npmjs.org/~tlevine) endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

This is exposed over [XML-RPC](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPIXmlRpc).